# VBA find row number , then use loop to find new cell with value in

Tags: vba, excel

I've got a workbook "Vendor Management Simplified8" with the data included in the "Overdue PO" worksheet and the organisation chart "Organisation Chart" in another worksheet [image: Org Chart]. Within the data sheet there is a list of people who manage the contractors. I want to loop through each of these names (There are no blank spaces in this column) and find their names within the Organisation chart and return the General Managers name and Department and return these values into columns N and O. The names may not be found in the organisation chart.

So far I've got this ...

```
Dim Cell As String
Dim loopy As Integer
Dim findrow As range
Dim finddata As Integer

loopy = 2
Do Until Worksheets("Overdue PO").range("E" & loopy).VALUE = "" 'loops through the name of person managing contractor
    Cell = Trim(Worksheets("Overdue PO").range("E" & loopy).VALUE) 'value which needs to be looked up

'finds the row number where value is found
    Set findrow = Worksheets("Organisation Chart").range("G:L").find(What:=Cell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False)

    If findrow Is Nothing Then
    Else: finddata = findrow.Row
    End If

        Do Until Worksheets("Organisation Chart").range("D" & finddata).VALUE <> "" 'if cell is not empty
            If Worksheets("Organisation Chart").range("D" & finddata).VALUE = "" Then
                finddata = finddata - 1 'go up the cells
            End If
        Loop

    Worksheets("Overdue PO").range("0" & loopy).VALUE = Worksheets("Organisation Chart").range("D" & finddata).VALUE 'department
    Worksheets("Overdue PO").range("N" & loopy).VALUE = Worksheets("Organisation Chart").range("D" & finddata - 1).VALUE 'general manager
    loopy = loopy + 1

Loop
```

So far - it finds the value and returns the row number in 'findrow', it loops up the rows in the Organisation Chart until the value isn't blank, then an error appears (run-time error 1004 - Application defined or object-defined error appears) on line `Worksheets("Overdue PO").range("0" & loopy).VALUE = Worksheets("Organisation Chart").range("D" & finddata).VALUE` when trying to enter the department into column O of the Overdue PO worksheet.

What am I doing wrong for to get this error? Is there an easier way to loop through up the column to find the General manager and department?

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Is that an `O` or a zero you have in that line?

Comment: You might also consider using `with...end with` statements. :-)

Comment: Thanks @Brian - I was staring at that for so long ... I can't believe it was such a silly mistake!! It works fine now thank you!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code amended using the `With` statement:

```
Dim Cell As String
Dim loopy As Integer
Dim findrow As range
Dim finddata As Integer

loopy = 2
Do Until Worksheets("Overdue PO").range("E" & loopy).VALUE = "" 'loops through the name of person managing contractor
    Cell = Trim(Worksheets("Overdue PO").range("E" & loopy).VALUE) 'value which needs to be looked up

    'finds the row number where value is found
    With Worksheets("Organization Chart")
        Set findrow = .range("G:L").find(What:=Cell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False)

        If findrow Is Nothing Then
        Else: finddata = findrow.Row
        End If

        Do Until .range("D" & finddata).VALUE <> "" 'if cell is not empty
            If .range("D" & finddata).VALUE = "" Then
                finddata = finddata - 1 'go up the cells
            End If
        Loop

        Worksheets("Overdue PO").range("O" & loopy).VALUE = .range("D" & finddata).VALUE 'department
        Worksheets("Overdue PO").range("N" & loopy).VALUE = .range("D" & finddata - 1).VALUE 'general manager
        loopy = loopy + 1
    End With
Loop
```

Comment: Thank you @Brian - This is really good because I rarely use With statements as I'm not sure how to do them.

Comment: With the code I wrote before and yours - There is an issue with the  If findrow Is Nothing Then
        Else: finddata = findrow.Row
        End If                 because it's still entering a value even if no match is found.

Comment: I would have to take a closer look at it. Can you post sample data I can copy to work with?

Comment: Also, I don't think you want to continue through the code if `findrow is Nothing`, correct? You want to loop to the next row.

Comment: I added a goto SkipRecord to skip down to the loopy = loopy + 1 to go onto the next record. I posted the answer below. Thank you for your help @Brian :)

Answer (score 0):

You have used a 0 (zero) and not the letter O.

Comment: If anyone tells you they have never done a similiar thing to this, they are lying. I've done more than my fair share im sure!

Answer (score 0):

I have cracked it! I put a goto SkipRecord to skip to the end to loopy = loopy + 1

```
Dim Cell As String
Dim loopy As Integer
Dim findrow As range
Dim finddata As Integer

loopy = 2

Do Until Worksheets("Overdue PO").range("E" & loopy).VALUE = "" 'loops through the name of person managing contractor
    Cell = Trim(Worksheets("Overdue PO").range("E" & loopy).VALUE) 'value which needs to be looked up

    'finds the row number where value is found
    With Worksheets("Organisation Chart")
        Set findrow = .range("G:L").find(What:=Cell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False)

        If findrow Is Nothing Then
        GoTo skiprecord
        Else: finddata = findrow.Row
        End If

        Do Until .range("D" & finddata).VALUE <> "" 'if cell is not empty
            If .range("D" & finddata).VALUE = "" Then
                finddata = finddata - 1 'go up the cells
            End If
        Loop

        Worksheets("Overdue PO").range("O" & loopy).VALUE = .range("D" & finddata).VALUE 'department
        Worksheets("Overdue PO").range("N" & loopy).VALUE = .range("D" & finddata - 1).VALUE 'general manager
skiprecord:
        loopy = loopy + 1
    End With
Loop
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Awesome!! Glad you got it figured out. :-)